# HX711 analog supply regulator current draw in sleep mode

Tags: power-supply, batteries, usb, adc, hx711

I use [HX711 ADC](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/ForceFlex/hx711_english.pdf) in my board that use LiPol battery as an only energy storage.
I used the same circuit as [Sparkfun's board](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13879).
[image: HX711 connection schematics]

In my case, VCC is provided by [STNS01](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stns01.pdf) battery management IC - so it's either battery voltage (3V-4.2V) or USB voltage when connected. The battery management chip also provides regulated 3.1V output and I use it to power MCU and all digital logic (including ADC's digital part).

When I power down the ADC before triggering MCU's low power state, the current draw of HX711 should be < 1uA according to the datasheet. This only applies when the VCC is 5V (USB is connected). When the VCC is in the battery's voltage range, the current draw is higher. For 4.2V, it's around 30uA. For 3V, it's around 13uA. It's somehow related to the internal linear regulator inside HX711.

Current draw with battery only power source (4.2V):
[image: Current draw with full battery]

Current draw with USB power source (5V):
[image: Current draw with 5V connected]

What could also play role in this behavior is that the STNS01 is by default in shipping mode (VCC and 3.1V outputs are not powered) and have to be activated by the USB voltage. So the VCC is 5V for a few seconds when the whole circuit is powered up (and HX711 is put into the sleep mode) and then drops to the battery voltage.

Why is there such an excessive current draw? It seems that the ADC was solely designed for 5V and its datasheet is misleading.